# V8 build error in windows

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I use the h file and dll file of the V8, was test from visual sudio 2015 c ++ console.

However, an error has occurred.

> v8console.obj : error LNK2001: 
>   "class v8::Platform * __cdecl v8::platform::CreateDefaultPlatform(int)"
>   (?CreateDefaultPlatform@platform@v8@@YAPAVPlatform@2@H@Z)

Why isn't it build correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with adding msvcrt.lib and msvcmrt.lib to the linker's Additional Dependencies property. Or, remove /Zl from the Command Line property page.
For further information please use the link-https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1tbxcxh.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx

Comment: Adding a msvcrt.lib and msvcmrt.lib to Linker of Additional Dependencies property is the same situation. And, there is no ZI in the code. It seems must not defined 'platform :: CreateDefaultPlatform' part is turned only in 'libplatform.h' declaration. I think there is problem in this part. Thank you.